# C# Console Application Throws error when debugging - when using breakpoint at the right location, no error is thrown

Tags: c#, active-directory, runtime-error, console-application, breakpoints

I'm currently editing a console Application on C# in Visual Studio 2019.
It's an application to synchronize some data on a database.
The last time I edited the code everything was fine and the code ran through.

At the moment I have a problem, where the app throws an catastrophic error in a passage, where I didn't change anything to the previous working code.

But if I set a breakpoint on the error throwing line in debug mode, it works just fine.
I searched a lot on the internet but it doesn't seem, that anyone else had a similar problem.

That's the code snippet which throws the error without the breakpoint on it:

```
// GetADContext just creates a new PrincipalContext with specific user and password
PrincipalContext pc = SomeDllClass.GetADContext();
// The line below throws an error - but only if there is no breakpoint
UserPrincipal adUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Sid, myClass.SID);
```

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution. Also deleted the .vs, obj and bin Folder. Nothing worked so far.

I have no idea why this is happening.
I hope anyone of you can help me with this weird behavior.

*Edit

Here is the full exception thrown:

```
"System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: Schwerwiegender Fehler (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Schwerwiegender Fehler (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
   bei System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
   bei System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
   bei System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   bei System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   bei System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)
   bei System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   bei System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)
   bei System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   bei System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)
   bei System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   bei System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   bei System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   bei System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
   bei System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
   bei System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   bei System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   bei System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
   bei System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   bei System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   bei System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   bei System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   bei System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   bei System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator..ctor(SearchResultCollection results, String parentUserName, String parentPassword, AuthenticationTypes parentAuthenticationType)
   bei System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.get_InnerList()
   bei System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.get_Count()
   bei System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRefHelper(Type principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime referenceDate, Boolean useSidHistory)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRefHelper(Type principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime referenceDate, Boolean useSidHistory)
   bei System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRef(Type principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime referenceDate)
   bei System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
   bei System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
   bei System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
   bei IMSTools.Base.IMSStd.GetUserPrincipal(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType type, String value)
   bei IMSMitarbeiterSynch.Program.SynchADS(List`1 mitarbeiter) in D:\\Git\\IMSMitarbeiterSynch\\IMSMitarbeiterSynch\\IMSMitarbeiterSynch\\Program.cs:Zeile 240.
   bei IMSMitarbeiterSynch.Program.SynchronizeData() in D:\\Git\\IMSMitarbeiterSynch\\IMSMitarbeiterSynch\\IMSMitarbeiterSynch\\Program.cs:Zeile 88.
   bei IMSMitarbeiterSynch.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\\Git\\IMSMitarbeiterSynch\\IMSMitarbeiterSynch\\IMSMitarbeiterSynch\\Program.cs:Zeile 53."
```

Comment: What is the exact exception thrown?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace, please?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out myself.

At first i use an **impersonation** to get admin rights to a directory where i need some files:

```
if (Environment.UserName.ToLower().Trim() != "adminuser")
{
    if (loggedOn = LogonUser("adminuser", "domainName", "password", 2, 0, ref token))
    {
        WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(token);
        wic = newId.Impersonate();
    }
}
```

I did this at the start of the program.
For the active-directory in the `PrincipalContext` i have to use another user for reading.

It looks like **impersonation** and `PrincipalContext` cannot operate correctly at the same time.

### Solution:

The solution was to **impersonate** only when i need access to the directory and undo it afterwards, so that **impersonation** and `PrincipalContext` never were active at the same time.

Maybe someone has the same issue and can fix it with this solution